# enable and disable input field

Tags: php, jquery

I want when I uncheck the checkbox `new_refund_amount` and `calculated_commission` should be disabled. there is a multiple order according to the manager and I want the select order with the help of check box and this code work for very first check box but not working on others

```
$result = $con->query($query);
echo "<table class='table'>
<thead>
<th>Profile Name</th>
<th>Refund Amount</th>
<th>Commission</th>
</thead>
<tbody>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                ?>  
<tr>
<td><?php echo "<input id='chkPassport' type='checkbox' class='chk_boxes1' name='payment1[]' value='{$row["id"]}'><lable class='ml-1'>{$row['profile_name']}</lable> "?></td>

<td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='new_refund_amount[]' value='{$row["order_amount"]}'  id='txtPassportNumber' disabled='disabled'>"; ?></td>
                
<td>echo  "<input  name='calculated_commission[]' type='text' value='$commission'readonly>";?></td>
</tr>
</tboday>
</table>

                            
                
             <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#chkPassport").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#txtPassportNumber").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#txtPassportNumber").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#txtPassportNumber").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, and by creating the same ID multiple times in a loop, you are violating that.

Comment: Unrelated fyi `<td>echo  "<input...` will not do what you think it does. `</tboday>` has a typo. Only `<tr>` are allowed as children of `<thead>`. `<lable...` has a typo

Comment: Ya but i get data from data base thats why id is same and getting issue with in in jquery

Comment: I haven't bost the full html code , sql query thats work fine

Comment: `id`s are _not_ the same _because_ you get data from the database. You have full control over `id='chkPassport'` or `id='txtPassportNumber'`

Comment: @brombeer Can you please post a code. if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do 2 things
firstly In Jquery uses clases to focus and disable textbox instead of 'ID'.

```
<td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='new_refund_amount[]' 
value='{$row["order_amount"]}' class='txtPassportNumber' disabled='disabled'>"; 
?></td>
```

secondly use

this.closest('tr')

for focus or disabled the specific row textbox

```
this.closest('tr').find('.txtPassportNumber').removeAttr("disabled");
this.closest('tr').find('.txtPassportNumber').focus();
this.closest('tr').find('.txtPassportNumber').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: <td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='new_refund_amount[]' value='{$row["order_amount"]}'  class='txtPassportNumber' disabled='disabled'>"; ?></td><td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
$("#chkPassport").click(function () {
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
this.closest('tr').find('.txtPassportNumber').removeAttr("disabled");
this.closest('tr').find('.txtPassportNumber').focus();
this.closest('tr').find('.txtPassportNumber').attr("disabled", "disabled");
 } else {$("#txtPassportNumber").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 }
]});
 }); </script>

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me...Thank you guys

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".chk_boxes1").click(function () {
                
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !$(this).prop("checked"));
                
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this

```js
function discount_type() {
if (document.getElementById('round').checked) {
    document.getElementById("discount").readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("discount").value= 'Now This input is readonly';
    document.getElementById("disacount_amount").readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById("disacount_amount").value= '';
}else{
    document.getElementById("discount").readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById("discount").value= '';
    document.getElementById("disacount_amount").readOnly = true;
     document.getElementById("disacount_amount").value= 'Now This input is readonly';
}
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="" id="round" onclick="discount_type()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Discount As Amount</td>
<table>
<td>Discount %<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="round form-control"  name="discount_per" id="discount">
</td>
<td>Discount Amount:<input value="This is readonly" name="discount" type="text" readOnly class="round form-control" id="disacount_amount">
</td>
 </table>
```

Comment: If that HTML is output inside a loop you'll also end up with multiple duplicate `id` attributes - which is invalid

Comment: it wont wok on multiple checkbox with same id